# ERROR: Ambiguous workspace

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

On the process of installing [rosjava_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html), on the line
"rosws merge /opt/ros/fuerte/.rosinstall" I get the following error:

"ERROR: Ambiguous workspace: ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/sam/my_workspace, /home/sam/my_workspace/android_core/.rosinstall"

As you probably have noticed, I changed the "electric" to "fuerte" in the command. Please correct me on that if I'm wrong.

If not, does anyone have any idea why I get this ambiguity problem?

Thanks so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34012/error:-ambiguous-workspace/) by [Sam_h](https://answers.ros.org/users/1955/sam_h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would have to disambiguate every time you are in an ambiguous situation. What causes ambiguity is having multiple '.rosinstall' files lying around.

You could rename or delete the one in /home/sam/my_workspace/android_core.

Is there a particular reason you want a .rosinstall there as well, as opposed to having the file named e.g. android_core.rosinstall?

rosws could have a switch that says it should use ROS_WORKSPACE in case of ambiguity, like --env or so. But for now I believe it is better to warn people that they have multiple .rosinstall files lying around.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosws tries to infer which workspace you want to work with. It looks at your current path and above, and also at the $ROS_WORKSPACE environment variable.

In this case it could not decide which .rosinstall you wanted to modify, since there was one at both:
/home/sam/my_workspace
/home/sam/my_workspace/android_core

You can disambiguate using e.g. -t /home/sam/my_workspace

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2